# find a chat by ID of two users

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have this code, I also use typeorm and nestjs

```
@Entity('chats')
export class ChatEntity extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToMany(() => UserEntity, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
    @JoinTable({})
    members: UserEntity[]
}
```

in members there can be two users, their order is not important and I need to find a chat so that in the chat there is a user with one id and also another user with a different id

There is such an alternative but it is very expensive and takes a lot of time

```
const chats = await this.chatRepository.find({
            where: {
                members: {
                    id:id1
                }
            },
            relations: ['members'],
            relationLoadStrategy: 'query'
        })

        const chat = chats.find(
            (chat) =>
                chat.members.some((user) => user.id === id1) &&
                chat.members.some((user) => user.id === id2)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce data processing, you can use whereIn (SQL).
To do it with TypeORM, you can use In from the typeorm package.
so you have to import it first

```
import { In } from 'typeorm';
```

and subsequently, since both IDs are provided, you can do a where in as follows:

```
const chats = await this.chatRepository.find({
      where: {
        members: {
          id: In([id1, id2])
        }
      },
      relations: { 
        members: true,
      },
      relationLoadStrategy: 'query'
    })
```